# Vuex-ORM GraphQL installation troubles

Tags: graphql, vuex, vuex-orm

I installed the [Vuex-ORM Graphql Plugin](https://github.com/vuex-orm/plugin-graphql) into an existing Nuxt project with Laravel/GraphQL API, so that I could try avoiding using the Apollo Cache. In one of my components though, I'm running:

```js
<script>
  import Notification from '~/data/models/notification';

  export default {
    computed: {
      notifications: () => Notification.all()
    },
    async mounted () {
      await Notification.fetch();
    }
  }
</script>
```

however I'm receiving the error `[vuex] unknown action type: entities/notifications/fetch`.

I looked through the debug log and found several available getters (entities/notifications/query, entities/notifications/all, entities/notifications/find, and entities/notifications/findIn). I tried running await Notification.all() in the mounted method which removed the error, however looking in Vuex the Notifications data object is empty.

Here is the rest of my setup:

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/vuex-orm',
  '~/plugins/graphql'
],
```

**plugins/vuex-orm.js**

```js
import VuexORM from '@vuex-orm/core';
import database from '~/data/database';

export default ({ store }) => {
  VuexORM.install(database)(store);
};
```

**plugins/graphql.js**

```js
/* eslint-disable import/no-named-as-default-member */
import VuexORM from '@vuex-orm/core';
import VuexORMGraphQL from '@vuex-orm/plugin-graphql';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import CustomAdapter from '~/data/adapter';
import database from '~/data/database';

// The url can be anything, in this example we use the value from dotenv
export default function ({ app, env }) {
  const apolloClient = app?.apolloProvider?.defaultClient;
  const options = {
    adapter: new CustomAdapter(),
    database,
    url: env.NUXT_ENV_BACKEND_API_URL,
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
  };

  if (apolloClient) {
    options.apolloClient = apolloClient;
  } else {
    options.link = new HttpLink({ uri: options.url, fetch });
  }

  VuexORM.use(VuexORMGraphQL, options);
};
```

**/data/adapter.js**

```js
import { DefaultAdapter, ConnectionMode, ArgumentMode } from '@vuex-orm/plugin-graphql';

export default class CustomAdapter extends DefaultAdapter {
  getConnectionMode () {
    return ConnectionMode.PLAIN;
  }

  getArgumentMode () {
    return ArgumentMode.LIST;
  }
};
```

**/data/database.js**

```js
import { Database } from '@vuex-orm/core';

// import models
import Notification from '~/data/models/notification';
import User from '~/data/models/user';

const database = new Database();
database.register(User);
database.register(Notification);

export default database;
```

**/data/models/user.js**

```js
import { Model } from '@vuex-orm/core';
import Notification from './notification';

export default class User extends Model {
  static entity = 'users';

  static eagerLoad = ['notifications'];

  static fields () {
    return {
      id: this.attr(null),
      email: this.string(''),
      first_name: this.string(''),
      last_name: this.string(''),

      // relationships
      notifications: this.hasMany(Notification, 'user_id')
    };
  }
};
```

**/data/models/notification.js**

```js
import { Model } from '@vuex-orm/core';
import User from './user';

export default class Notification extends Model {
  static entity = 'notifications';

  static fields () {
    return {
      id: this.attr(null),
      message: this.string(''),
      viewed: this.boolean(false),

      // relationships
      user: this.belongsTo(User, 'user_id')
    };
  }
};
```

**package.json**

```json
"@vuex-orm/plugin-graphql": "^1.0.0-rc.41"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in a Hail Mary throw to get this working, I ended up making a couple of changes that actually worked!

If other people come across this having similar issues, here's what I did...
In my nuxt.config.js, swapped the order of the two plugins to this:

```
plugins: [
    '~/plugins/graphql',
    '~/plugins/vuex-orm',
],
```

In my graphql.js plugin, I rearranged the order of the options to this (database first, followed by adapter):

```
const options = {
  database,
  adapter: new CustomAdapter(),
  url: env.NUXT_ENV_BACKEND_API_URL,
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
};
```